# Python exec() function - SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to run multiple discord bots in one file and I decided it would be easiest to loop over it and use the exec function to declare the bots and the events for them.

The code I have an issue with:

```
for i in range(23):
    exec("bot" + str(i + 1) + " = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=INTENTS)")

for i in range(23):
    exec("@bot" + str(i+1) + ".event")
    async def on_ready():
        loginmsg()
```

The error I get

```
    exec("@bot" + str(i+1) + ".event")
  File "<string>", line 1
    @bot1.event
               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Please try to keep it simple, I am a bit of a newbie.

Comment: `exec` cannot execute `"@bot" + str(i+1) + ".event"` because it is not a statement. If it's supposed to be a decorator, then you need also to give it the definition you want to decorate. Better still, do not use `exec`. If you want a sequence of numbered variables, use a list.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Because of the nature of the project, I can't use a list. I was wondering if you knew of a way to create multiple decorators with a variable,
like
`@bot"VARIABLEHERE".event`

Comment: I'm not sure what "the nature" is of your project, but `exec` is considered poor practice and vulnerable to attack. There is nearly always a way around using `exec`. We might be able to help with a little more context.